# Stripping leading whitespace from arguments passed to user defined functions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I strip leading whitespace from parameters passed to user defined functions with gnu-make?

For example:

```
define FOO
# --- some build rules

# run the built target
/home/user/dir/bin/$(1)

endef
```

The following call works correctly, since there is no leading whitespace:

```
$(eval $(call FOO,my_test ) )
```

Unfortunately the following fails, because `$(1)` has a leadning space

```
$(eval $(call FOO, my_test ) )
                  ^
                Additional space to 'prettier' formatting
```

this ends up expanding to:

```
/home/user/dir/bin/ $(1)
                   ^
                 Leading whitespace
```

How can I strip leading whitespace from arguments passed to user defined functions?

Is it bad form to do this or should I simply assume that arguments are passed without leading whitespace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `strip` function:

```
define FOO
# ...
/home/user/dir/bin/$(strip $(1))
endef
```

For details, see [Text Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html). Because of this, and to avoid using `strip` everywhere, it is best to avoid spaces after commas when passing arguments to functions.

Comment: Execellent! that was really cheesing me off :-)